# Actionscript 3 how to delete instance from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, event-listener, removechild

So I have two movieclips, sRP_mc and dP_mc, on the first frame. Now, when either of the movieclips are clicked on, then I want the movieclip to be removed from the stage and then I want the frame to change (I want the movie to go to frame 5). On frame 5, there is a close button, which, if clicked, takes you back to frame 1 (but when it takes you back to frame 1, I want the movieclip which was clicked on to not be there anymore). Here is my code for my first frame (frame 1).

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();
if (sRP_mc.visible == true) {
    sRP_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sRPClicked);
    function sRPClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
        sRP_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sRPClicked);
        removeChild(sRP_mc);
        gotoAndPlay(5);
    }
}

if (dP_mc.visible == true) {
    dP_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dPClicked);
    function dPClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
        dP_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dPClicked);
        removeChild(dP_mc);
        gotoAndPlay(10);
    }
}
```

and on frame 5, there is a close button and the code is this.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();
close_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeScreen);
function closeScreen(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

and on frame 10 there is also a close button the code is this.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();
close_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeScreen2);
function closeScreen2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

As you can see, if sRP_mc or dP_mc are removed using the removeChild method, then sRP_mc and dP_mc should not be visible (.visible != true) but when I play this, it says that sRP_mc and dP_mc are always visible and the child does not get removed completely from the stage (or I think the isntance keeps coming back whenever I go back to frame 1). Why is it doing this and how would I fix it?

Comment: you have some fundamental problems with the syntax of your code (eg: function definitions inside if statements). Assuming you are using Flash Pro, select "Strict Mode" in ActionScript settings and Flash Pro will show you all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

When the object is removed from the stage the visible property isn't changed to false unless you do so manually. Here's a better to way to check if an item isn't on the stage (I also cleaned up your inline function):

```
if (sRP_mc.stage != null) {
    sRP_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sRPClicked);
}

function sRPClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    sRP_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sRPClicked);
    removeChild(sRP_mc);
    gotoAndPlay(5);
}
```

If an object is removed from the stage its stage property is set to null. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hm okay it still doesn't work. I added a trace statement after the removeChild statement and it does trace so it is removing the child, but when it goes to frame 5, and then after the before clicks the 'close' button and it goes back the frame 1, the movieclip comes back for some reason. Is it because I actually put the movieclip onto the stage on frame 1 and not used addChild?